How to update permissions for a user in looker studio api?
I try to update permissions for some users. Here is a req body:
{
      "permissions": {
          "permissions": {
              "EDITOR": {
                  "members": [
                      "user:test1@gmail.com"
                  ]
              },
              "VIEWER": {
                  "members": [
                      "user:test2@gmail.com"
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  }

and then i get  Error: Got error "Forbidden", status - "403", body: {"error":{"code":403,"message":"Owner is not allowed to be modified","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
Even though i am NOT trying to modify the owner
I tried to modify the req body but it didnt help

Please update your question so that it represents a minimal repro of your issue. What API are you using? How are you getting the permissions? etc. It is likely (familiarity with other Google auth systems) that the policy can't be updated in part as you show but must be updated in its entirety. Usually, this is done by GET'ing the policy (with an eTag), mutating it and then attempting to PATCH it back.
